償う and the に particle
''香純さん 私は何をしたら あなたに償える．．．？''
''Kasumi what can I do to make it up (for/to) you?'' Was my understanding of it
I'm a bit confused by the sentence considering 償う is a transitive verb so is it grammatically correct? I read it somewhere on a manga and always thought it was intransitive considering the particle usage...
Is it possible that with に償う You are making up / compensating to someone while を償う Is to make up for an objective loss?

「私はこれをあなたにあげる」 is a sentence with a similar structure

Yeah it made more sense after you mentioned it. Guess I got too rigid about the intransitive and transitive rules while forgetting the language is a living thing itself

English transitive verbs require some explicit object (even if it's just "it"), but the を-marked object of a Japanese transitive verb can always be omitted if it can be inferred from the context. And transitive verbs can take other arguments marked with various particles other than を.

ひとりで食べる to eat [it] alone
彼女と作る to create [it] with her
彼に渡す to pass [it] to him
あなたに償う to make [it] up for you

In your case, the implied object can be something like 間違い, 損失 or 失敗.
